# How to filter only row in which every factor "A" is present in both year 2018 and 2019

Tags: r

In R, I'm looking for a way to select only rows with animals that are present in year 2018 AND 2019
given a dataframe like this:

```
 Animal     Year    Week    Value
      A     2018    15      14
      B     2017    15      6
      B     2019    16      9
      A     2018    17      17
      B     2019    15      25
      A     2019    16      27
      B     2017    15      20
      C     2019    17      6
      B     2018    18      3
      A     2019    15      5
```

Let's suppose animal "C" is recorded only during 2019 I want to drop all rows with C.
The expected output is the same dataset but with the "C" line removed.

Moreover, I'm looking for a way to select only those animals which have more than 2 observations (rows) per Week.
The expected output would be:

```
     Animal     Year    Week    Value
          B     2017    15      6
          B     2019    15      25
          B     2017    15      20
```

cause only the animal "B" has more than 2 observations per Week.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given data?

Comment: Your first question can be solved easily by `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Animal) %>% filter(all(c(2018, 2019) %in% Year))`. As for the second question, could you specify its expected output?

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thank you for your answer, it works.
As for the other question, the problem is related to what I want to do next, that is:
df <- df %>% group_by (Animal, Week) %>% sample_n (size = 3)
which sends me an error "Error:` size` must be less or equal than 2 (size of data) ". Since I don't want to sample with replacement, I thought I'd first make a selection of those animals that have at least 3 observations per week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Animal) %>%
  filter(all(c(2018, 2019) %in% Year))

#   Animal  Year  Week Value
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A       2018    15    14
# 2 B       2017    15     6
# 3 B       2019    16     9
# 4 A       2018    17    17
# 5 B       2019    15    25
# 6 A       2019    16    27
# 7 B       2017    15    20
# 8 B       2018    18     3
# 9 A       2019    15     5
```

**Question 2**

```
df %>%
  group_by(Animal, Week) %>%
  filter(n() > 2)

#   Animal  Year  Week Value
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 B       2017    15     6
# 2 B       2019    15    25
# 3 B       2017    15    20
```